# Is there an example where the Apollo client and the Apollo server are used together

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I have not found an example where Apollo client and apollo server are used together. I need a sample to better learn and understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you are full nice tutorial using client and server, that covers all you need of apollo to develop your app:

```
Part 1 (this part): Setting up a simple client
    https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/full-stack-react-graphql-tutorial-582ac8d24e3b

Part 2: Setting up a simple server
    https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/react-graphql-tutorial-part-2-server-99d0528c7928

Part 3: Writing mutations and keeping the client in sync
    https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/react-graphql-tutorial-mutations-764d7ec23c15

Part 4: Optimistic UI and client side store updates
    https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/tutorial-graphql-mutations-optimistic-ui-and-store-updates-f7b6b66bf0e2


Part 5: Input Types and Custom Cache Resolvers
    https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/tutorial-graphql-input-types-and-client-caching-f11fa0421cfd

Part 6: Subscriptions on the server
    https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/tutorial-graphql-subscriptions-server-side-e51c32dc2951
```

Comment: Can you make those links clickable?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you should use **react starter kit**

https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit

checkout the branch: **feature/apollo**

There are both server and client.

Comment: thank you , I want to a sample that using apollo server and apollo client together.

Answer (score 0):

This one seems to be a comprehensive, easy-to-follow tutorial on Full-Stack Apollo GraphQL using Apollo Server and Apollo Client together... No Express, no Redux, all Apollo.

https://developer-log.netlify.com/full-stack-apollo-graphql-tutorial-pt-1-setup/

Disclaimer: It's my tutorial :)